# Windows shared printer reprints jobs from the day before

Tags: windows, printing, network-printer

I have two PCs here, one of which, *PC1*, runs Windows 7 Pro and shares a Samsung ML-1660 Series printer (\PC1\Samsung).

The other PC, *PC2*, is running Windows XP Pro and has installed the shared printer.

Everyday, both PCs prints on this Samsung printer and at the end of the day, both PCs are shutdown.

Next day, when we power on these PCs, all print jobs sent from PC2 to \PC1\Samsung are printed again.

Do you know how can I fix this? Currently, we are keeping PC1 on but I don't think that's a good idea. I'd rather have the printer work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt problem is with printer os server PC (`\\PC1\Samsung`).

Check `PC2` for corresponding settings, make sure print queue is empty after printing.

- If it's not, make sure "Keep printed documents" is unchecked (both on client and server).

  [image]
- make sure print queue directory is empty (`c:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS` on PC1 and a subdir of `c:\Windows\System32\spool\SERVERS\PC1` on PC2).
- If all is clean, this must be some software spooling more documents on startup.